# What species is this beetle (trichius family)

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I took this picture in Jura region (Northern Switzerland, alt: ~700m) of that beetle (July 2018). It was taking food from a flower of a `Morus nigra`.

[image: trichius-up]
[image: trichius-front]

It seems to be part of the `trichius` genus but I want to report the exact species.

In Switzerland we have mainly:

- Trichius fasciatus
- Trichius rosaceus
- Trichius sexualis

I think by the color of the hairs it would be a `Trichius fasciatus`.

Can someone confirm the species and what field marks I can use to make the distinction between those three species?